# using elastic-search as database in django

Tags: django-models, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I want to use `elastic-search` as database in my project which I build on `django` framework. As I learn, `elastic search` is used with together a database through `haystack` where `elastic-search` is used for only indexing and fast retrieval issues. [Here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html) it is explained how to integrate a database and `elastic-search` with `haystack` However, I would like to use `elastic-search` without a database, in other words I will index all data. I did not see anything like below that you can use `elastic-search` as database backend in `django` settings module.

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
    },
}
```

}

Is not it possible to use only `elastic-search` with model layer of `django`?
[Here](https://github.com/aparo/django-elasticsearch) is the `django-elasticsearch` backend and in the examples section it does in the way I would like to do but I do not know whether it is storing first in a database and indexing on `elastic-search` or just store and indexing on `elastic-search`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer to your question is "no."  I looked into this a while ago, and found that there was a project to create an elasticsearch database engine (https://github.com/aparo/django-elasticsearch), but with a last commit in 2011, I would not think that it is viable with post 1.0 versions of ES, and possibly 1.6.x versions of Django.